# Loop through all files/images in a folder with Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, static-files

I have an app with some products and each product has a gallery with a different amount of images. Each of the images has a name that is completely random / no correlation with the other image names.

Each of the product images are in `/src/assets/images/products/:id/`.

I need to add the paths to a gallery component but I can't loop through them because the names are random. Is there any way to just loop through each file from a folder using only Angular? If not can I do it on the back-end without renaming the files? I'm also running the app on a Node.js back-end if that matters.

Comment: This is not possible with frontend only. You have to use node.js fs package and provide a request for your frontend to get alle image ids.

Comment: check this [https://gist.github.com/kethinov/6658166](https://gist.github.com/kethinov/6658166)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do that with frontend.
What you need to is using your back-end and return file in it.

You are using NodeJs as back-end so can use the `fs.readdir` or `fs.readdirSync` methods.

**fs.readdir**

```
const testFolder = './images/';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file); // use those file and return it as a REST API
  });
})
```

**fs.readdirSync**

```
const testFolder = './images/';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
  console.log(file);
})
```

Read the full [documenation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), it may help you to how you can proceed.