# looping through images in assets folder

Tags: angular

I have a bunch of images in my assets files.

Is there a way to loop through them all at once or do I have to  `<img src"...">` all of them one by one?

I am using angular

Comment: from server pick up the folder path and return detail's as list & bind them .

Comment: You can write all images src in array and use `*ngFor` after. You can also look at this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445719/loop-through-all-files-images-in-a-folder-with-angular

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through all files/images in a folder with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445719/loop-through-all-files-images-in-a-folder-with-angular)

Comment: if you know all the file name then create array with those file name and loop