# How to fetch all playing card images to add them to an array using Angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, image, typescript

I have an Angular application and I want to create Blackjack. For this I copied images of all playing cards into the `/assets` directory.

I want to loop through the images in the folder to add the images(or source url) to an array, but like the following answer is saying this is not possible in the frontend.   [Loop through all files/images in a folder with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445719/loop-through-all-files-images-in-a-folder-with-angular)

But then, how should I add those to an array? Is it required to edit the backend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a deck of cards. You don't need to query what they are on the back-end, because they are never going to change. Just generate the array on the front-end using a filename pattern.

```js
   function cardSet(rank) {
      return Array(13).fill(0).map((x, indx) => `card-${rank}-${indx + 1}.png`);
   }

   const cards = [
      ...cardSet('club'),
      ...cardSet('diamond'),
      ...cardSet('heart'),
      ...cardSet('spade')
   ];
   
   console.log(cards);
```